# How to figure out what version of Jetty to use?

Tags: java, maven, jetty

In my build for my maven java webapp, I have the following plugin:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
   <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>8.1.8.v20121106</version>
</plugin>
```

But the version of Jetty I'm using has that annoying "null identity service" thing, so I want to upgrade the version I'm using, but I can't figure out any good way to determine what version of jetty would be best for me to run.

I've found [this Jetty documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/what-jetty-version.html) which shows some info, but only about the big version numbers, like 6, 7, 8, and 9. I'm using javax.servlet 3.0.1, so I think I want jetty 8 or 9.

[This Jetty documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/quickstart-jetty-coordinates.html) seems to be telling me how to figure out individual versions to use, but I don't entirely get it. It looks like from that maybe I should use 9.0.0.RC0?

On the [maven repo page for jetty](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-server) I can see a bunch of versions, but the most recent version 8 is the one I'm using with the bugged identity service thing, and the 9s are all "milestones" which I assume means they're relatively untrustworthy? I don't really know what it means by "milestone".

I'd appreciate some guidance or advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need WebSockets or SPDY you can stick to the latest release of Jetty 8. Look at this page and pick the highest 8.1.x version:

http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.eclipse.jetty%22%20AND%20a%3A%22jetty-server%22

Comment: Well, that did help me upgrade to a better version of jetty 8. Any reason you know to not use 9?

Comment: You can give it a try, but I would wait for the final release of Jetty 9.

Comment: Jetty 9.0.0.RC0 is already pretty stable. You can give it a try. It contains some major refactorings in the network layer and you'll keep the option for SPDY, etc. in the background. If you encounter any issues, just report them to the jetty-user mailinglist and they should get resolved quickly.

Answer (score 8):

Locate the start.jar in your distribution. Then use the "--version" flag: 
java -jar start.jar -- version

Comment: Found extra space between '--' & 'version'. This worked for me.

`java -jar start.jar --version`

Comment: It doesn't work for me. When I run ```java -jar start.jar --version```, I get this prompt ```Usage: java [-DDEBUG] [-DSTART=start.config] [-Dmain.class=org.MyMain] -jar start.jar [--help] [config ...]```

Answer (score 0):

How about this [Jetty_Version_Comparison_Table](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Starting/Jetty_Version_Comparison_Table) and this [Feature list](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature). If you need xxx feature, then look into it, it will show you which version you need to support this feature.